# How to use innerHTML and ejs together inside for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, ejs

I want to list each message using `innerHTML`.
If I didn't have to use `innerHTML`, I could easily do like the follows.

```
<div>
  <% for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) { %>
    <p><%= messages[i] %></p>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

The reason I have to use `innerHTML` for this purpose is that I have React.js code that gets minimized by webpack, so I can't put ejs code where I want in the React code.
To get around this problem, I need to put `id` in the React code so that I can place the messages where I want. So I tried the follows.

React Code:

```
<div id="messagesGoHere"></div>
```

index.ejs Code:

```
<script>
  <% for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) { %>
    document.getElementById("messagesGoHere").innerHTML += "<p><%= messages[i] %></p>";
  <% } %>
</script>
```

This returned error saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

I use node.js, express, and redis to store the messages.

I appreciate any suggestions.

**Update:**

The following is how I render `messages` object.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // Get messages
  client.lrange('chat:messages', 0, -1, function (err, messages) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      // Get messages
      var message_list = [];
      messages.forEach(function (message, i) {
        message_list.push(message);
      });
      // Render page
      res.render('index', { messages: message_list });
    }
  });
});
```

Things to note:

- The first snippet of code that I provided in my question that doesn't rely on `innerHTML` works absolutely fine, which proves that my server-side code is correct.
- As for the ejs code in `<script>` tag, if I don't use `i` variable and instead use `0` like this `"<p><%= messages[0] %></p>"`, it successfully returns the first message as many as the count of for loop, which also proves that my server-side code is working.
- The problem is the **usage of for loop** along with ejs and innerHTML. Not my server-side code or any other code.

Comment: Is that a server-side error? Can you show full error?

Comment: I think this is a client-side error since the `innerHTML` isn't working. That error is all I got.

Comment: why you are adding ejs code inside <script> tag ? messages is a javascript variable or ejs?

Comment: My question already describes why I need to put ejs in <script> tag. messages are messages stored by redis that are rendered using node.js like this "res.render('index', { messages: message_list });"

Comment: your syntax seems wrong, if you are writing inside script tag use javascript loop syntax not ejs tags. why do you need <% for for loop

Comment: Because if you don't use <%, `i` variable isn't defined.

Comment: I would go so far to say that using server side rendering for something like chat messages is the wrong way to go about it. I'm sure you already realize you are passing `messages` twice. Once with `res.render`, and once via react. The only conceivable reason I can see for this is that you want the initial render to have those messages (SEO perhaps?). I would take the easy way out and replace the entire prerendered-section. Use the `I could easily do this without innerHtml` method you mention. When there is an update to the data, you hide pre-rendered data and show your react component instead.

Comment: Actually using server side rendering for chat messages is the way to go. Use Websockets to render real-time messages and server side rendering to show those stored persistent messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had been completely lost on this issue, but finally made it work.

There was nothing wrong on any of my code in the first place.

As I initially thought, the following snippet of code was correct.

```
<script>
  <% for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) { %>
    document.getElementById("messagesGoHere").innerHTML += "<p><%= messages[i] %></p>";
  <% } %>
</script>
```

It worked after I deleted my redis data for `messages` and recreated new data.

So I believe there was something hindering in my redis data.

I apologize for not understanding the real problem.

I also want to thank everyone who helped me in this post.

Answer (score 0):

> assign messages to javascript variable

```
 <script>
var msgs= <%=messages %>
      for (var i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("messagesGoHere").innerHTML += "<p>msgs[i] </p>";
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: @tet Try to change this `"<p>msgs[i] %></p>"` to `"<p>" + msgs[i] + "</p>"`

Comment: @Molda I tried that but returned error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. I also tried changing the `msgs` value to a string like this `"<%= messages %>"`, but returned error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Comment: @tet can you share your messages object?  and slso try  msgs=<%-
 JSON.stringify(messages) %>

Comment: @subrahmanyabhat I updated my question, hope you'll see it. `msgs=<%- JSON.stringify(messages) %>` didn't work. Error `Uncaught ReferenceError: messages is not defined`